# Xamarin forms navigation page back button mvvm command

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a property in XAML to set when back button pressed launch MVVM method through command?

Or another way to do it avoiding code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) to bind [NavigationPage.Popped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.popped?view=xamarin-forms), [NavigationPage.PoppedToRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.poppedtoroot?view=xamarin-forms) events to a `Command` on XAML.

Comment: I've tried with Popped event and didn't work. It works using Disappearing event from the ContentPage.

Comment: You can custom the back button and perform method in your own back action. Disappearing event will also triggered when you push to next page.